# How to predict trained model with one image?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I want to test the trained model with a single image(rgb). But I am encountering an error. I used cat and dog images while training the model.Also, while creating the model, I got the first layers from resnet50. I created the last layers myself. Before exporting the dataset to the model, I did some preliminary work and converted the classes to 0-1 values.(with encoder cat:0,dog:1) Now I want to test this model with a dog image. I expect it to return 0 or 1, but I have a problem.

my code blok:

```
*from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform
# dimensions of our images    -----   
img_width, img_height = 750, 422
# load the model we saved
model = load_model('.../Resnet50_Save_model.hdf5')
test_image = image.load_img('.../5c02ed550f25442260cff6ab.jpg', target_size=(img_width, img_height))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
test_image = Image.open('.../5c02ed550f25442260cff6ab.jpg')
test_image = test_image.resize((750,422))
test_image = test_image / 255.0
test_image = test_image.reshape(224,224)
result = model.predict(test_image, batch_size=1)
print(result)*
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-cd9abec3a0ce> in <module>()
     23 # test_image = test_image.reshape(224,224)
     24 
---> 25 result = model.predict(test_image, batch_size=1)
     26 print(result)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1478 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1468 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1461 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1434 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:274 assert_input_compatibility
        ', found shape=' + display_shape(x.shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(1, 750, 3)

 - List item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the shape of your input (1, 750, 3)
doesn't match the expected shape by your model (None, 224, 224, 3).

I recommend you resize your image to 224 x 224 first, then normalize it using the division by 255. After that expand the dimensions so it becomes (1, 224, 224, 3) and try again.

Comment: I did as you said, but the result is not what I wanted. I wanted it to return 0 or 1. output like this: [[8.989863e-24 1.000000e + 00]]. what does it mean?

Comment: That means that the softmax results for the label 0 are basically 0(8.989863e-24) and the ones for 1 are 1(1.000000e + 00). So your answer was that the test image is 1 so it should be a dog!

Comment: so is it working properly? I just retried using a cat image and [[9.9998772e-01 1.2290835e-05]] gave such an output. then that means the image is a cat.

Comment: It is working properly indeed. And the image of the cat is giving you a high probability(9.9998772e-01) for the label 0 so it is correctly predicting it as a cat!

Comment: I have another problem, I want to use this model in an interface and for this I used ngrok and streamlit library. I wrote a code blog. But this doesn't work properly. Can you help again?

Comment: By the way, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I suggest you to open a new question about the use of the ngrok and streamlit libraries to create an interface. 

By the way if you could accept my answer as correct that would be very nice of you!

Comment: İ did it :) I added a new question and shared a photo about the error. I'm waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two image loading operations, you can select one of them.

```py
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image

# load the model we saved
test_image = image.load_img('.../5c02ed550f25442260cff6ab.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image) / 255.0

model = load_model('.../Resnet50_Save_model.hdf5')
result = model.predict(test_image, batch_size=1)
print(result)
```

Comment: İsmail Bey kodu şöyle düzelttim : test_image = test_image.resize((224,224))
test_image = np.asarray(test_image) / 255
test_image = test_image.reshape(1,224,224,3) . Fakat istediğim gibi bi sonuç döndürmedi ben verisetini modele vermeden önce encoding işlemi yapmıştım yani kedi için 0 köpek için 1 değerlerini döndürmesi için. Bu kod bloğunun çıktısı şu şekilde : [[8.989863e-24 1.000000e+00]] . Bu ne anlama geliyor ?

Comment: Modeli eğitmeden önce model.compile(...) kısmına loss = "binary_crossentropy" bunu kullanmak yerine loss="categorical_crossentropy" kullandım acaba bu yüzden mi böyle bir sonuç döndürdü. Deep learning konusunda yeniyim bu yüzden sonradan öğrendim ikili sınıflandırmalarda binary kullanılması gerektiğini.

Comment: @BüşraDuygu firstly there is not allowed any language except English in stackoverflow, because of open society. After the prediction, you can call  `np.argmax(..)` to get the classification index.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you for informing. I use np.argmax(...) its working correct thanks :)